# Get output by given input -Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
echo “Enter Number:” 
read n1 
awk '/^$/ {ca=""; cp=""} /^#/ {ca=ca " " $0} /^$n1/ && ca {cp=ca; ca=""} /^$n1/ {print $0 " " cp}’ FILENAME
```

after entering the number i should get output by given input.

Enter number:1

Output

1 test   happy  1234 980  capture

Please suggest me the above script

Comment: I think you should probably look at how to use awk before writing things in it

Comment: after running the script system should ask enter the number, after entering number the script will execute based on given number.

Comment: What does your input data look like? How does the input number correspond to the data in the file?

Comment: input data will be like below                                     1.1.1  robert   80   48 67 87 89
1.1.2 renold   80   49  87  98  90
1.1.3   gracy   100   100 87 78 78
1.1.4   paul 25 45 33  20   19                                           
1.1.1  robert   80   48 67 87 89
1.1.2 renold   80   49  87  98  90
1.1.3   gracy   100   100 87 78 78
1.1.4   paul 25 45 33  20   19                                    The number(1.1.1 or 1.1.2...etc) is present multiple times in a file   i have to parse the file and fetch the file based on number.It's 1GB  file

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass shell variables with awk's `-v` option:

```
awk -v patt="^$n1" '
    /^$/ {ca=""; cp=""} 
    /^#/ {ca=ca " " $0} 
    $0 ~ patt && ca {cp=ca; ca=""}
    $0 ~ patt {print $0 " " cp}
’ FILENAME
```

Comment: This might be more clear, in the sense of separation of concerns, if the variable passed to awk was `n1` instead of `patt` and then the usage was `"^"n1`. (That being said I'll admit that's more confusing to read in awk itself since it is more likely to look like a syntax error so someone unfamiliar with awk.)